# El significado de "pops" de pollo

Tags: terminología

Quisiera confirmar si **pops** (parece que no es el pop que se define en RAE) es la abreviatura de "palomitas". Y si la respuesta es un "sí", ¿me podrían explicar el porqué? Muchas gracias.

Según RAE, [**pop**](https://dle.rae.es/pop) significa -

> 1. m. Estilo musical de origen angloamericano nacido al final de los años cincuenta del siglo XX, caracterizado por la creación de
>      canciones de ritmo marcado acompañadas de instrumentos eléctricos y
>      batería, y que busca lograr una gran difusión comercial.
> 2. m. arte pop.
> 3. adj. Perteneciente o relativo al pop. Música, ritmo pop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pues me temo que no, que no significa palomitas.

Como indica el D.R.A.E, la palabra **pop** se ha tomado del inglés, más concretamente

> Del ingl. pop, acort. de popular 'popular'.

Hasta donde yo sé los **pops de pollo** son un producto específico de Telepizza, que consiste en pequeñas bolitas de pollo rebozado. Supongo que por su tamaño parecido al de las palomitas de maíz, los encargados de marketing decidieron llamarlo así.

Palomitas de maíz en inglés se dice **popcorn**.

De acuerdo al Oxford Dictionary

> [**popcorn**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/popcorn)
>   Maize of a variety with hard kernels that swell up and burst open when heated.

Es decir

> Variedad de maíz con cascara dura que se hincha y se abre cuando se calienta

Las palomitas de maíz, popcorn, son un producto de consumo masivo relativamente reciente según este [artículo](https://www.pbs.org/food/the-history-kitchen/popcorn-history/), en inglés, donde se comenta su historia. El origen del término no está claro pero puede estar relacionado con el sonido que hacen al abrirse: pop, pop, pop.

La palabra **[pop](https://www.lexico.com/definition/pop)** en inglés como verbo puede significar

> Make or cause to make a light explosive sound.

Es decir

> Producir o causar un ligero sonido explosivo

Con lo cual tenemos otro de los posibles orígenes de popcorn: maiz explosivo.

Desconozco si en inglés a las palomitas se las conoce también como **pops**. No he encontrado referencia alguna que respalde ese supuesto. En general palomitas = popcorn.

Comment: I think we always call it popcorn not pops.

Comment: ¡Miles de gracias por sus explicaciones ‍♂️!